# Fancybox2 update title after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have looked for the answer myself, but being that I'm posting, I haven't had much luck. Fancybox is found at: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

I'm making a photo gallery for myself, and this is working excellent. However, I want to get image descriptions into the titlebox. My image descriptions are stored elsewhere. (I am actually pulling the descriptions from Flickr, but that's largely irrelevant.)
Right, so- each image holds an html5 data called "id" this is linked to the flickr image ID.
Before I open fancybox, I do this:

```
var sDescription;

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    beforeLoad: function () {
                        var id = this.element.data('id');
                        var data = {
                            imgID: id
                        };
                        //setupBlocks();
                        loadData(data);
                    }

function loadData(data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Ajax/getDescription.php"
                        ,
                        data: data
                        , success: function (res) {

                            sDescription = res;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

All this is doing is passing the ID to my own script, a page that only holds a string of text, and then putting it into a string.

```
afterLoad: function () {

                        this.title= this.element.data('title')+sDescription;
                    }
```

Now I'm simply updating the title to hold the title as well as description. When I open the first image, it makes the ajax request, and after it downloads the text fancybox will open and show me the title as: Megan 0014"The Wanderer"
When I press left/right I can see the beforeLoad callback is calling the ajax request, but the text doesn't update (still says The Wanderer on a completely different model-the name prefix is indeed corrected) unless I close/open fancybox, then the string is correct. 
Other things I have tried: making a reference to "this" in a variable and passing it to loadData, and setting the text once the ajax loads, but title does NOT seem to update at all once fancybox has been opened, unlike a normal div in html.

As a last resort I might preload each string and set it in an array, but what I would rather do is just update the string on success.

I tried very hard to keep this as generic as possible... but let me know if there's any questions.

Edit: If I press an arrow key twice (and provided I give it a second to load), the text updates to the previous image's description, it's just a matter of fancybox not refreshing the string.

Edit2: Yeah, I edit a lot. I know. I discovered the onUpdate callback, so in my ajax success I call $.fancybox.update();

my onUpdate looks like this:

```
onUpdate : function () {
                        console.log("on update");
                        this.title = this.element.data('title') + sDescription;
                        console.log(this.title);

                    }
```

The title in the console is CORRECT- the title on the page is not. This tells me that, no, the title cannot be changed without closing the window...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel dumb for not thinking of this but I forgot I could modify the div directly.

```
$( ".fancybox-title" ).html(this.element.data('title') +" "+ sDescription)
```